# Formula month rolling 3 meses Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data, dax

estoy atascado con un problema en power BI.

Basicamente necesito crear una visualizacion de Month Rolling acumulado de 3 meses, lo he intentado de multiples maneras pero sigue dandome errores o diferencias en los resultados, les mostrare lo ultimo que probe que me dio el resultado mas cercano pero sigue sin ser lo que quiero.

Cree dos medidas DAX que son estas:

```
JRR Satisfacción 3M = 

var Sat_1 = CALCULATE(
    (AVERAGE(Encuestas[SATISFACCION_VA])),
    DATEADD('dim Date'[Date],-1,MONTH))

var Sat_2 = CALCULATE(
    (AVERAGE(Encuestas[SATISFACCION_VA])),
    DATEADD('dim Date'[Date],-2,MONTH))

var Sat_0 = CALCULATE(
    (AVERAGE(Encuestas[SATISFACCION_VA])),
    DATEADD('dim Date'[Date],0,MONTH))

Return (Sat_1 + Sat_2 + Sat_0)
```

Y esta:

```
JRR Satisfacción EVO_13M 3M = 

CALCULATE([JRR Satisfacción 3M], all('dim Date'), 
DATESINPERIOD('dim Date'[Date], 
SELECTEDVALUE('dim Date'[Date]), -13 , MONTH))
```

Fijense que la segunda hace referencia a la primera, y en conjunto basicamente lo que hacen es calcular el valor de Satisfaccion para el mes seleccionado en el eje de fechas, el mes anterior y dos meses atras, luego suma estos valores.

Por ultimo estos valores los incerta en la segunda medida que es la que va al grafico que deberia mostrar estos valores month rolling de 3 meses para cada mes de un periodo de 13 meses hacia atras, es decir si empezamos con el mes de diciembre 2022, deberia mostrar los valores month rolling hasta el mes de diciembre 2021.

Hasta aqui creo que todo bien, pero cuando grafico esto lo que ocurre es esto:

Esta es la grafica con los valores originales, es decir los valores de satisfaccion para cada mes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la grafica aplicando las dos medidas anteriores, la cual deberia mostrar los valores acumulados de los ultimos 3 meses para cada mes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan el resultado esta bastante bien, con el problema de que en noviembre y diciembre 2022 no se muestra valores acumulados adecuadamente.

Podrian ayudarme a resolver este tema??

Saben alguna otra forma de obtener el resultado que quiero?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la siguiente medida te servirá. Simplemente calcula la media (AVERAGE) en el periodo indicado (`DATESINPERIOD`). El `MAX('dim Date'[Date])` se ajustará en tu gráfico al contexto de cada periodo del eje X, en tu caso meses.

```
JRR Satisfacción EVO_3M 3M = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(Encuestas[SATISFACCION_VA]),  
    DATESINPERIOD('dim Date'[Date], MAX('dim Date'[Date]), -3 , MONTH)
  )
```